# How to get a credit card as a minor?

Tags: bank-account

To my understanding, to get a credit card as a minor I would have to be 18 or I would have to be on an account with one of my parents. Unfortunately for me my parents don't have good credit. I have a job and would like to buy equipment for producing music at home and it would be easier for me to pay for the equipment monthly, but I don't want my parents' credit restricting my ability to get a credit card. Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Unemancipated minors can't enter into legally binding agreements, so you're almost certainly unable to put yourself deep in debt.  Do what young people have been doing forever: save up and then **buy used equipment** for cash.

Comment: Buying things that you can't currently afford and ultiamtely don't need on a credit card on the assumption that your job will continue is probably how your parents got a poor credit record. Either buy cheaper equipment now, or save up and buy what you really want when you have the money.

Comment: Legal questions should have a country specified.

Comment: @Scott I think this good comment should be written up as an answer - particularly due to the last line in the question, "Is there anything I can do?"

Comment: I'm just gonna lay this terrible comment right here:
I got a credit card when I was 17 years old. I simply gave them an 18 year old birthdate. They approved me for the card instantly. In hindsight it was a terrible idea. I ruined my credit and it took me a while to repair. I'm only saying its possible - but don't do this! Lying about your age on a credit application is probably illegal.

Answer (score 7):

> In general, [minors cannot enter into legally binding contracts](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/sandberg-getting-credit-card-when-under-18-1377.php) --
>   which is what credit accounts are -- so an individually held card is
>   probably not an option for you right now.

You will not be approved for a credit card because you are minor. The only option credit card wise for you is for your parents to add you on as an [authorized user](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/should-you-make-your-teen-credit-card-authorized-user/) onto their accounts. The upside is that you and your parents can work out a monthly payment for the amount you spend on your equipment, the downside is that if your parents don't pay their credit card bill, your credit score/report can be negatively affected. (This also depends on the bank, however, all the banks I bank with report monthly payment activities on authorized users' credit reports as well. There might be a bank that doesn't.)

In terms of credit cards, there is nothing you can do. What you could do as the comments have suggested is either save up money for the equipment you want, or buy something cheaper.

Comment: "Unfortunately"? I think this might be best edited to "fortunately"

Comment: @nardnob I guess it is unfortunate for his situation, but fortunate in general?

Comment: Agreed. Take it from someone drowning in debt. Run away from credit cards as fast as you can unless you're responsible enough to pay off the entire balance each month (I wasn't)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a job and would like to buy equipment for producing music at home and it would be easier for me to pay for the equipment monthly

I just want to address your contention that it would be easier to pay monthly, with an interest calculation.  Lets say you get a credit card with a very reasonable rate of 12% and you buy $2,500 of equipment.  A typical credit card minimum payment is interest charges + 1% of the principle.

```
Month      Principle         Interest        Payment
 Jan         $2,500           $25.00         -$50.00
 Feb         $2,475           $24.75         -$49.50
 Mar         $2,450           $24.50         -$49.01
 Apr         $2,426           $24.26         -$48.51
 May         $2,401            etc
```

You can see how this is going.  You've paid nearly $200 to clear about $100 off your principle.  Obviously paying the minimum payment will take forever to wipe out this debt.  So you pay more, or maybe you get 0% interest for a while and take advantage of that.

Paying $100 per month against $2,500 at 12% per year will take 29 months and cost about $390 in interest.  At $200 per month it'll take 14 months and cost $184 in interest.  Also note, you'll probably get an interest rate closer to 16 or 17%.

It's always easier to pay small amounts frequently than it is to pay a lot of money all at once, that ease has a cost.  If you're buying the gear to start a little business, or you already have a little business going and want to upgrade some gear, great; disciplined debt handling is a wonderful skill to have in business.  If you want to start yourself in to a new hobby, you should not do that with debt.

If interest rates are low enough financing something can make sense.  0.9% apr on a car, sure; 15% apr on a mixing board, no.  Credit card interest rates are significant and really should not be trifled with.